# Pytest Django function mocking APITestCase

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to create tests involving sending GET requests to my API using pytest-django and I need a function used in the views to be mocked.

I have tried mocker from pytest-mock and unittest.mock.patch and every time I mock this function in some test case it remains mocked in the other tests as well.

First .py test file:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestFirst(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.patcher = patch(app.views.function)
        cls.patcher.start()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.patcher.stop()

    def test_something(self):
        get_data = self.client.get('/some/url')
        self.assertEqual(200, get_data.status_code)
```

and then followed by a test in some completely different .py file:

```py
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestSecond(APITestCase):
    def test_something_else(self):
        get_data = self.client.get('/some/url')
        self.assertEqual(200, get_data.status_code)
```

When debugging the first test case, the method is patched correctly. However when running the second test, the method remains patched and the mock object keeps the number of calls received.

Am I missing something important?

EDIT: I tried both patching the file where the method is defined and name of  the method in views, but always keep getting same result.

EDIT2: Worth noting that when I change the order of the tests, the second one completes correctly, but the first one is unable to have the method patched and calls it unpatched, therefore fails.

Comment: I was never using pytest-django, but I know tests isolation might be a pain sometimes. Are you sure that you are not running tests in parallel? Does it happen also when you use the decorator style @patch('app.some.module.function') on a method and then run test within context manager from the passed mock? Fixtures with scope?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. All in all about 10 hours already spent trying to fix this. Right now the method keeps getting patched even though I deleted all the patching from all tests and kept only these two. I am thinking that it must be some sort of caching, perhaps using pipenv might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using the SimpleTestCase superclass. I have still no idea why this was happenning, but doesn't seem to be anymore.